# Calculating the mean for intervalls within a variable

Tags: r, mean

Lets suppose I have a dataset like: 
`dat <- rnorm(25)`
and a vector, which represents specfic indices of my data: `v <- c(1, 8, 13, 17, 25)`

How can I calculate the mean for the following intervalls: 1-1, 1-8, 8-13, 13-17, 17-25?

In general: I want to average spezific intervalls within `dat` depending on an index vector `v` which is meaningfull, but also quite irregular.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cut` to get the interval groups and `aggregate` to calculate `mean` per group.

```
aggregate(dat, list(interval=cut(seq(dat), c(0,v))), mean)
#  interval          x
#1    (0,1] -0.5604756
#2    (1,8]  0.3484638
#3   (8,13]  0.1704305
#4  (13,17]  0.4599013
#5  (17,25] -0.6754733
```

Or in case you want overlaps of the intervals on the first and last position you can use `sapply`.

```
sapply(seq(v), function(i) mean(dat[v[max(1,i-1)]:v[i]]))
#[1] -0.56047565  0.23484641 -0.06881816  0.44807533 -0.54510397
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `findInterval` to form groups and use `tapply` to get `mean` for each group.

```
tapply(dat, findInterval(seq_along(dat), v, left.open = TRUE), mean)

#         0          1          2          3          4 
#-0.5604756  0.3484638  0.1704305  0.4599013 -0.6754733
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- rnorm(25)
v <- c(1, 8, 13, 17, 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(x = dat) %>% 
    group_by(Interval = findInterval(row_number(), v, left.open = TRUE)) %>% 
    summarise(x = mean(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` and `cut()` to create groups, then calculate the means in each group via `sapply`, i.e.,

```
r <- sapply(split(dat,cut(seq_along(dat), c(-Inf,v))),mean)
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- rnorm(25)
v <- c(1, 8, 13, 17, 25)
r <- sapply(split(dat,cut(seq_along(dat), c(-Inf,v))),mean)
```

giving

```
> r
  (-Inf,1]      (1,8]     (8,13]    (13,17]    (17,25] 
-0.6264538  0.2397270  0.3101554 -0.2877232  0.3456389
```